# How can I have text in a textbox be used to filter rows in an html table using jquery?

Tags: jquery, filter, html-table

I have an html table like this:

```
<table>
       <tr><th>Column Heading</th></tr>
       <tr><td>ABC</td></tr>
       <tr><td>DEF</td></tr>
       <tr><td>ABC</td></tr>
       <tr><td>223</td></tr>
       <tr><td>ABCDEF</td></tr>
</table>
```

and I have an html textbox and I want the functionality when I type text into the textbox, it uses that to filter the html table rows based on content in that first column

So if I type in "AB" into the textbox one 3 rows would still show and the other ones would be hidden.  If I remove the "AB" then all rows show again.

What is the most efficent way to hide rows in an html table based on filtering based on content entered into a textbox?

Comment: have you check my answer Is it work for you? I dont know why downvoted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this in html:-

```
<input type="text" class="search"/>

<table>
<thead>
   <tr><th>Column Heading</th></tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
   <tr><td>ABC</td></tr>
   <tr><td>DEF</td></tr>
   <tr><td>ABC</td></tr>
   <tr><td>223</td></tr>
   <tr><td>ABCDEF</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

and Jquery:-

```
$('.search').keyup(function(){
    var val=$(this).val().toLowerCase();    
    $('table tbody tr').hide();
     var trs=$('table tbody tr').filter(function(d){
       return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val)!=-1;
     });
     trs.show();   
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gq2pvLjz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should get you going in the right direction

```js
$('#myTextbox').keyup(function() {
 var text = $(this).val();
 
 $('#myTable tr').each(function() {
  if($(this).find('td').first().html() == text) {
   $(this).show();
  }
  else {
   $(this).hide();
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: instead of checking for equality you could also use $(this).find('td').first().html().indexOf(text) >= 0, that would show table rows that contained the text entered even if they weren't equal

Answer (score -1):

**HTML**

```
<input type="textbox" id="text"/>
<table id="table">
       <tr><th>Column Heading</th></tr>
       <tr><td>ABC</td></tr>
       <tr><td>DEF</td></tr>
       <tr><td>ABC</td></tr>
       <tr><td>223</td></tr>
       <tr><td>ABCDEF</td></tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#text').keyup(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $('#table tr').each(function() {
        var val = $(this).text();
            if( val.toLowerCase().indexOf(text)>=0) {
            $(this).show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dsreovdh/)**

Comment: Check my answer may help you. If you cant understand let me know.